# Angular material with bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular-material

I am building an application using Angular Material 7.3.1 and now I want to use the Bootstrap 4 Grids. After installing Bootstrap my application is padded on the left and right side like shown in the image:[image: bootstrap padding]

How can I void this padding?

Comment: You have to override the padding property.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: the div where you don't want padding. Add a new class to that div with padding:0 ;

Comment: thanks for the instructions. i did it but the white space is still there. some padding is indeed gone. maybe angular material is not working with bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following in the src/styles.css file and there are no spaces any more:

```
.container {
    max-width: 100%!important;
    padding-right: 0px!important;
    padding-left: 0px!important;
}
```